# How to make selenium execute two different buttons one after the other

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have selenium trying to execute two different buttons one after the other and I'm getting different errors depending on the method I try.
So this is what the code looks like

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elem=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@data-componentname='gender']//span[text()='Male']/preceding::input[@type='button']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
```

And I am try to implement the following line

```
joinBtn=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='JOIN US']"))).click()
```

However every time I try I get an error such as

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
```

The JOIN US html has a dynamic ID so every refresh it's different

```
<div id="712eb3a9-b9a7-4cf7-8c0f-b4ae2b710e36" class="submit-button joinSubmit component blurred">

<input id="f357cd20-f2d5-4b1c-a379-8ad475a10daf" type="button" value="JOIN US">
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a element with value join us ? Add the html pleaee

Comment: html has been added

Answer (score 0):

Invoking `click()` doesn't returns anything. Hence while your program tries to assign `null` to **joinBtn** you see the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I Just created two different functions and ran 1 after the other

```
def male():
    elem=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@data-componentname='gender']//span[text()='Male']/preceding::input[@type='button']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)


def join():
    joinBtn=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='JOIN US']"))).click()
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", joinBtn)
```

There seemed to be conflict so separating them between each execution has solved the issue. The `execute_script` member wants to click both buttons so keeping them separate works best.